# How can i make a number like 123 into a string with ascii in C++?

Tags: c++, string

I want to make a number like 77 into a string but I can't use ascii because it's only from 0-9. Is there some way to make numbers become a string? So this is the result at the end: You input a number and it outputs the number but as a string. Example: input:123; output:"123".

Comment: `std::to_string` worth a try

Comment: This "number" will most-likely already be in the format of a string when the user inputs it.

Comment: [A good reference might help](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: _but i can't use ascii because it's only from 0-9_ Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: By the way, you should probably [read a couple of good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), because then you learn that a "string" is really nothing more than a collection of *single characters* (where each character could be a single digit, in whatever *character encoding* you want).

Comment: Well I want to use ascii but ascii can only go up to 9 so i think numbers with two digits can't use ascii

Comment: @Dordor: But a string can have an arbitrary number of characters.

Comment: Perhaps this will be elucidating: `std::string seven = std::to_string(7); std::string stringSum = seven + seven; std::cout << stringSum;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each digit can use ASCII. The number 123 uses a 1, a 2, and a 3, and the string that represents that value uses the characters `'1'`, `'2'`, and `'3'`.

The way to do the conversion yourself is to get each digit by itself and add the digit to `'0'`. Like this:

```
int value = 123
std::string result;
while (value != 0) {
    int digit = value % 10;
    char digit_as_character = digit + '0';
    result.insert(0, 1, digit_as_character);
    value = value / 10;
}
```

This is pretty much what you'd do if you were doing it by hand:

- start with the value get the last digit of the value by dividing by
  10 and looking at the remainder
- write down a digit for the remainder
- divide the value by 10 to remove the last digit, since you don't need
  it any more.

Comment: Note that this works with any encoding supported by C++. Have an upvote.

Comment: @Bathsheba — yes; I didn’t want to over-complicate this for a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

Who said anything about ascii? The C++ standard doesn't.

Use the platform-independent `std::to_string(77)` instead.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string